# Move image to the right of the card in a Bootstrap Card

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend, bootstrap-5

Inside a Bootstrap Card I want to move the image to the right of the title and text, but in my code the image stays below them. How do I get it to go all the way to the right of the screen, by the side of the title and text?

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="card bg-transparent border-0 text-white mb-3" >
        
       <div class="row g-0">
          <div class="col-md-6">
             <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Lorem title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="../assets/images/cp/sobre-cid-2.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded-start" alt="cid-2">
        </div>

    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.img-fluid.rounded-start {
    height: calc(120px + 10vw);
    width: 90vw;
    border-radius: 30px 0px 0px 30px;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.card-title {
    font-family: Martel;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}

.card-text {
    font-family: Martel;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

[image]

I've tried adding `float-right` in the class and in the CSS but it didn't work, nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the image `div` inside the row `div`. Also, change `col-md-6` to `col-6`:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="card bg-transparent border-0 mb-3" >
        
       <div class="row g-0">
          <div class="col-md-6 order-2 order-md-1">
             <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Lorem title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
             </div>
          </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 order-1 order-md-2">
            <img src="../assets/images/cp/sobre-cid-2.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded-start" alt="cid-2">
        </div>
       </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: This worked perfect, thank you, but I have to make another question, is it possible to make the image go to the top in responsive? I tried switching the position of the image code in the HTML but it messed up the desktop version. And I ended up adding `col-md-6` anyway, which made the image go to the bottom in responsive (mobile)

Comment: Yes, you can do it with `.order` classes. You can specify the order for each screen size. I updated my answer, can you try it again?

Comment: Perfect again! Thank you, you're amazing. I'll search up to learn about `.order` too.

Comment: You are welcome. You check the official docs for the `.order` classes: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes